# how to set custom UILabel text on UITableView prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

(Looking at this post 3 years later, I feel like the tone of this post is quite impolite... Might because my English wasn't good back then. Sorry about that.)

Hello everyone,

I'm quite new to OC and having some problems regarding `UITableView`

So I created a `UITableView` in storyboard and a Prototype Cell for it. Then I put a `UILabel` on the prototype cell.

My question is how to set this `UILabel` text without creating a new class for `UITableViewCell` or using `xib`.

(Don't want to create too many classes...)

Comment: Use `viewWithTag:`?

Comment: @Larme I tried this. But it seems it only worked for the first cell.

Comment: do you need a single UIlabel Only in Cell?

Comment: Add some sample code here, so we can understand what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Larme It works. Don't know why I failed just now......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this code helps for you

First of all we need to give the label tag in storyboard and write this below code in cellForRowIndex delegate

```
UILabel * myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

myLabel.text = [self.namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Here cell is your table view cell and 5 is the tag you have already given in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can get subview of your UITableViewCell like below:

```
UILabel *label = [[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

label.text = @"your text";
```

Comment: I use   for (UILabel * sub in self.tableView.subviews){NSLog(@"%@", sub.class);}  to see what's in the tableView. But there is no UILable in it.

Comment: Since your table view contains one or more cells, in that case this will return object for all labels at one time. But as you need to change the text of your single label of cell at once. So above will work fine i guess.

Comment: I made a mistake just now. It should be  for (UILabel * sub in cell.subviews). But I still didn't get what I want. So I printed [[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex: xx] at each index and finally find which one is my UILabel. Anyway, it works too. Thank you for help!~

Comment: That's what i was trying to tell you. All your controls of a cell are in contentView. Anyways, you welcome. Please mark answer so that it can help out others too.